# Comportamento de um usuário que fica fazendo a mesma pergunta repetida várias vezes

Tags: debate, comportamento

Existe um usuário que está insistindo desde o dia 23/out/2017 (menos de uma semana) na mesma pergunta. Mas não insiste de maneira a tentar corrigir o que já existe, mas a mesma pergunta acabou de entrar em sua terceira encarnação. Em ordem cronológica:

- [nao consigo converter o programa abaixo para c++](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/248808/64969)
- [Como converter este código de Pascal para C++?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/249202/64969)
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/250647/64969

Aparentemente, a ideia é traduzir um código de [pascal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pascal) para [c++](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).

Nas três perguntas o código é simplesmente apresentado, sem texto algum, sem guia algum para dizer onde tem encontrado problema de tradução ou um pedido sincero e desesperado de "não sei inquérito estou fazendo, alguém pode me explicar desde o começo?". Na terceira versão da segunda encarnação da mesma pergunta, ele apresenta uma tentativa de tradução, mas também sem código acompanhando.

Conforme a pergunta foi evoluindo, eu e outros usuários tentamos interagir com o AP, mas o máximo de resposta que obtivemos foram edições cruas do código da pergunta. Ora com a formatação em bloco de código, ora com a tentativa de transformação para C. Em outros momentos foi pedido qual o ponto de dificuldade, mas sem resultado (pelo menos nenhum comentário na minha lembrança nem algum comentário visível para mim agora).

No estado atual, o @VictorStafusa deu uma penteada e deixou o seguinte [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/249202/converter-de-pascal-para-c#comment514113_249202):

> Coloquei um pouco de texto em sua pergunta para tentar deixá-la respondível. Com isso pode-se fechar as duplicatas e reabrir-se essa daqui.

Dado esse contexto, a pergunta que eu quero fazer é:

- Como devemos nos portar perante usuários lacônicos e teimosos assim?
- Os comentários pedindo para aprofundar a pergunta e deixá-la respondível foram suficientes?

  - Se não, como poderíamos ter agido?
- Tem alguma espécie de bloqueio no sistema para evitar que este usuário em específico continue a sujar com perguntas soltas sem maiores detalhes?
- Como comportarmos para que novos usuários não repitam esse comportamento? Basta pedir para fazer o tour e ler o FAQ de como criar boas perguntas?
- Já temos alguma enlatada para casos semelhantes? Faz sentido existir enlatada para esse fim?

Comment: Além do que foi respondido, vale para outras situações do site: negativos e fechamentos disparam um _trigger_ depois de um tempo, fazendo o usuário ter que "esperar um pouco" pra postar novas perguntas. Já discuti isso muito no passado, pois sempre desaprovei os votos "assistencialistas" dados pela comunidade. Há algum tempo a comunidade estava num clima pró-mimimi, que não era saudável pra rede.

Comment: Sempre gostei mais do `@Pateta` e do `@Donald`

Comment: @brasofilo, obrigado pela edição. Manterei isso em mente

Comment: Pra quem não entendeu o comentário do @GuilhermeNascimento: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/6513/revisions

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Como devemos nos portar perante usuários lacônicos e teimosos assim?

O SO tem help, meta, sala de chat etc. e por fim tem pessoas que tentam ajudar através dos comentários nas perguntas. Se nada disso ajudou, não tem mais nada que se possa fazer. Vota pra fechar e bota na conta do papa.

- Os comentários pedindo para aprofundar a pergunta e deixá-la respondível foram suficientes?

Não deveriam nem ser necessários, afinal esse tipo de comentário é uma cortesia. Mas foram, sim, mais do que suficientes. Aparentemente o AP leu ao menos um comentário, então, se não conseguiu melhorar a resposta, não tem mais o que se fazer.

- Se não, como poderíamos ter agido?

Agimos corretamente ao votar para negativar e para fechar.

- Tem alguma espécie de bloqueio no sistema para evitar que este usuário em específico continue a sujar com perguntas soltas sem maiores detalhes?

Se ele insistir com esse comportamento, ele será [naturalmente bloqueado pelo sistema](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583/2263584).

- Como comportarmos para que novos usuários não repitam esse comportamento?

O SO é bastante resiliente com relação a isso. Acho que basta continuarmos por fazer o que já fazemos que o site se auto-regula naturalmente.

- Basta pedir para fazer o tour e ler o FAQ de como criar boas perguntas?

Isso é uma cortesia. Cada pessoa disposta a ajudar, ajuda de sua forma. Eu costumo editar as perguntas conforme o possível e deixar algumas dicas em comentários. Na maioria das vezes os novatos são pessoas que já deram alguma olhada no site antes e fazem perguntas quase completamente alinhadas com o site, requerem apenas uma pequena forcinha para fazerem parte da comunidade. Só coloco os links pro FAQ quando alguma pergunta está realmente fora de escopo. Mas isso varia, pessoa a pessoa.

- Já temos alguma enlatada para casos semelhantes? Faz sentido existir enlatada para esse fim?

Sim e sim. A resposta enlatada é o voto para fechamento. Note que cada motivo para fechamento tem um parágrafo pronto que descreve porque a pergunta não se encaixa no site.